# filter django filterset on gte, lte and none

Tags: django-rest-framework

How do you filter a field on gte, lte or none within django's `drf_filters.FilterSet`. I can setup a gte, lte filter correctly, but I can't see how the same field can match on null.

```
class CustomFilterSet(drf_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomModel
        fields = {
            'custom_field': ('lte', 'gte')
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its simplier than expected:

```
class CustomFilterSet(drf_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomModel
        fields = {
            'custom_field': ('lte', 'gte', 'isnull')
        }
```